# Render dynamic HTML with embedded Razor variables using MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some encoded Html which have any number of 1000s of different Razor variables embedded within it that I have stored and need to retrieve **from the database**. I want to be able to render this in a MVC/razor view.

Just one simple example of the html saved on the database (it can be more complex):

```
"<span>Your page is @Config.PageColour and you have page size of @Config.PageSize</span>"
```

**MessageController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ShowMessage()
{
    var htmlToDisplay = _messageDAL.getHtmlMessage();
    var messageVm = new MessageVm
    {
        DisplayMessage = htmlToDisplay;
    };

    return View("Index.cshtml", "", messageVm);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<html>
    @Html.Raw(@model.DisplayMessage)
</html>
```

**Results**

When I run this the rendered page looks like this:

> Your page is **@Config.PageColour** and you have page size of **@Config.PageSize**

But I want it to interpret the value of the Razor variable with the html block and should look like this:

> Your page is **Blue** and you have page size of **`A4`**

Really stuck on this so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this line. I hope this may help.

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@model.DisplayMessage))
```

**EDIT 1**

You can use any Razor Compiler like the one mentioned below

**RazorEngine**:

```
string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(@model.DisplayMessage, new { Name = "Name" });
```

RazorEngine does not support any of the Mvc helpers such as Html and Url. Since these libraries are supposed to exist outside of Mvc and thus require more work to get them to work with those helpers.**

**EDIT 2**

You can use a Razor compiler that allows you to use HTML templates called RazorEngine which can be found at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

From **Visual Studio**, using the **Package Manager Console** command:

```
Install-Package RazorEngine
```

After installation I changed my controller as follows:

**MessageController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ShowMessage()
{
    var htmlTemplate = _messageDAL.getHtmlMessage();

    var htmlToDisplay = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(htmlTemplate , "messageTemplateKey", null, new { Name = "some model data" });

    var messageVm = new MessageVm
    {
        DisplayMessage = htmlToDisplay;
    };

    return View("Index.cshtml", "", messageVm);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mukesh Kumar . Tried that, doesn't seem to do anything sadly.

Comment: Kindly check the edited answer. I hope that might help.

Comment: I had to do some digging around and made some changes but ultimately your second answer provided enough for me to write a complete and working solution which I've also posted. Thanks @Mukesh Kumar.

Comment: That's great. Mark it as an answer, which may help others. Also if other changes are required do edit the answer or let me know I'd do it.

Comment: Yep. I edited your answer with my details. Saved me a lot of work there. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91609/discussion-between-mukesh-kumar-and-jeff-yates).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Razor compiler that allows you to use HTML templates called RazorEngine which can be found at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

From **Visual Studio**, using the **Package Manager Console** command:

```
Install-Package RazorEngine
```

After installation I changed my controller as follows:

**MessageController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ShowMessage()
{
    var htmlTemplate = _messageDAL.getHtmlMessage();

    var htmlToDisplay = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(htmlTemplate , "messageTemplateKey", null, new { Name = "some model data" });

    var messageVm = new MessageVm
    {
        DisplayMessage = htmlToDisplay;
    };

    return View("Index.cshtml", "", messageVm);
}
```

And it worked first time. Big thanks to **@Mukesh Kumar** who provided the vital clues to rewrite the code which I've posted as a complete and working answer here.