# How to save the entire HTML with dynamic values and retrieve it correctly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanted to have a dynamic footer for my page. So, I have an HTML editor page which saves an HTML into the database and retrieves it as my footer. I need to call a dynamic value from it.

```
<div>
   <p>*This is in my footer (upcoming holidays: @holidays)</p>
</div>
```

@holidays is instantiated on the main html page.

```
  @{
    var holidays = Html.Raw(ViewBag.Holidays);
   }
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>...</body>

    <div>@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.FooterContent)</div>
  </html>
```

I am getting the design of the HTML from the database correctly but is not getting the value of @holidays.

[I am getting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNoCa.png)

How do I get to read the dynamic call?

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990996/render-dynamic-html-with-embedded-razor-variables-using-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest you how I would achieve the functionality you are expecting.

Since your footer is coming from DB, You can use string formatting to insert your dynamic content directly to the html string as follows.

```
        // Portion that you want to customize
        var input = "Dynamic content";

        // HTML test coming from DB
        var footer = string.Format(
            @"<div>
                <p> *This is in my footer(upcoming holidays: {0})</p>
             </div> ", input);
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.FooterContent)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: Rather than storing your templates in DB there could be better ways like using partial views.

Comment: Wow!Thank you for saving my time

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Hope it answered what you looked for.